# Spacing between parboxes distributed unevenly

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, parbox, baseline

I'm fairly new to Latex and not sure, if the solution to my problem is an obvious one. I'm trying to get the spacing between the lines of those parboxes to be distributed evenly; the same distance between an item and its description and description and next item name. Having a description with multiple lines seems to mess it up a little. Also, a 'g' or a 'y' increases the spacing, even though I set the baseline to 1.2 times the font size.

```
\documentclass{article}
% remove indentation of the first line of a paragraph
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
% set the length of spacing between paragraphs
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\newcommand*\Entry[3]{%
    \fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont
    \parbox[m]{0.8\linewidth}%
        {\textbf{#1}\;\dotfill}\;\textbf{\$\hfill#2}%
            \ifx&#3&%
                \par%
            \else%
                \par\parbox[m]{0.8\linewidth}{#3}\par%
            \fi%
}


\begin{document}


\Entry{Item 1}{100}{Description 1}
\Entry{Item 2}{120}{Description 2}
\Entry{Item 3}{120}{word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word }
\Entry{Item 4}{120}{Description 4}
\Entry{Item 5}{120}{Description 5 that is so long that it gets split up into multiple lines.}
\Entry{Item 6}{120}{Description 6 that is so long that it gets split up into multiple lines.}
\Entry{Item 7}{120}{Description 7}
\Entry{Item 8}{180}{word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word with g or y }
\Entry{Item name with y or g}{120}{Description 9}
\Entry{Item name with y or g}{120}{}
\Entry{Item name with y or g}{120}{}
\Entry{Item }{120}{}
\Entry{Item 10}{120}{Description 10}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```latex
\documentclass{article}
% remove indentation of the first line of a paragraph
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
% set the length of spacing between paragraphs
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\newcommand*\Entry[3]{%
    \fontsize{10pt}{13pt}\selectfont
    \begingroup
    \makebox[0.8\linewidth][l]{\textbf{#1}\;\dotfill}\;\textbf{\$\hfill#2}%
            \ifx&#3&%
                \par
            \else
                \par\rightskip0.2\linewidth #3\par
            \fi
    \endgroup
    % \medskip % better no to separate items ?
}


\begin{document}

\Entry{Item 1}{100}{Description 1}
\Entry{Item 2}{120}{Description 2}
\Entry{Item 3}{120}{word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word }
\Entry{Item 4}{120}{Description 4}
\Entry{Item 5}{120}{Description 5 that is so long that it gets split up into multiple lines.}
\Entry{Item 6}{120}{Description 6 that is so long that it gets split up into multiple lines.}
\Entry{Item 7}{120}{Description 7}
\Entry{Item 8}{180}{word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word with g or y }
\Entry{Item name with y or g}{120}{Description 9}
\Entry{Item 10}{120}{Description 10}
\end{document}
```

which appears to achieve you query about

> he same distance between an item and its description and description and next item name.

But I would rather had some spacing in there as indicated in a comment.

[image: items evenly separated vertically]

Comment: Thank you, that does the trick! The only issue I have with makebox is that the text overflows when it is longer than those 0.8\linewidth. Is there a solution to that?

Comment: I assume you then want the dotfill and dollar and stuff on last line? Use `\rightskip=0.2\linewidth` for the whole thing like this `\begingroup\rightskip0.2\linewidth \textbf{#1}\;\dotfill\rlap{\makebox[.2\linewidth]{\;\bfseries\$\hfill#2}}\par \ifx&#3&\else#3\fi \par\endgroup`.